# showing individual values out of foreach with values from checkbox

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, foreach

Am a newbie,i have a checkbox,that passes values to a foreach loop which then gives me a result of selected items as a list working fine.However i would like to obtain to obtain all the individuals separately probably each under a new variable so that i can reuse all the checked values separately.Please help

THE FORM.

```
<form action="" method="post"
       <a target="_blank" href="paris.jpg"><img src="flour.jpg" alt="Paris" style="width:150px"></a><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="50 kg flour-50ksh"/><input type="checkbox" name="shipping[]" value="$50.00"><label>50 kg flour-50ksh</label>
       <a target="_blank" href="paris.jpg"><img src="milk.jpg" alt="Paris" style="width:150px"></a><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="50 kg milk-50ksh"/><input type="checkbox" name="shipping[]" value="$10.00 "><label>50 kg milk-10ksh</label>
       <a target="_blank" href="paris.jpg"><img src="maize.jpg" alt="Paris" style="width:150px"></a><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="50 kg maize-50ksh"/><input type="checkbox" name="shipping[]" value="$20.00 "><label>50 kg maize-20ksh</label>
       <a target="_blank" href="paris.jpg"><img src="oil.jpg" alt="Paris" style="width:150px"></a><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="50 kg oil-50ksh"/><input type="checkbox" name="shipping[]" value="$30.00 "><label>50 kg oil-30ksh</label>
       <a target="_blank" href="paris.jpg"><img src="rice.jpg" alt="Paris" style="width:150px"></a><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="50 kg rice-50ksh"/><input type="checkbox" name="shipping[]" value="$40.00 "><label>50 kg rice-40ksh</label><br/>
       <a target="_blank" href="paris.jpg"><img src="soap.jpg" alt="Paris" style="width:150px"></a><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="50 kg soap-50ksh"/><input type="checkbox" name="shipping[]" value="$50.00"><label>50 kg soap-50ksh</label>
       <a target="_blank" href="paris.jpg"><img src="juice.jpg" alt="Paris" style="width:150px"></a><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="50 kg juice-50ksh"/><input type="checkbox" name="shipping[]" value="$50.00"><label>50 kg juice-50ksh</label><br>
       <label for="name"> Mobile:</label>
       <input type="number"  placeholder="10" id="mobile" name="mobile"  maxlength="10" size="10" pattern="[0-10]{10}" required/>
       <label for="name">Names:</label>
       <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required formtarget="_blank"/>  
       <label for="location">location details:</label>
       <input type="text" id="location" name="location" required/>
       <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/><br>
```

Form has double checkboxes ,ignore the other.

PHP CODE

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
foreach($_POST['day'] as $day)
{
echo $day;
}
}
?>
```

WHAT I GET
50 kg milk-50ksh50 kg maize-50ksh50 kg oil-50ksh50 kg rice-50ksh50 kg juice-50ksh

how can i make it be like a==50 kg milk-ksh50 b=.... c=...so that i can assign maybe $john=a?  then i will be able to reuse $john?

Please help out.

Comment: I must not understand what you are asking, because it doesnt make sense to declare redundant variables to the global scope.  In plain terms, please describe what you are trying to accomplish with this task.

Comment: I simply want to obtain all the values that have been checked from the checkbox..Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In your checkboxes, if you want to generate an associative array, you can fill the square brackets in your checkbox fields with your desired single letters like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="day['a']" value="50 kg flour-50ksh"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="day['b']" value="50 kg milk-50ksh"/>
...
```

Then you can access them like this:

```
$_POST ['day']['a']
$_POST ['day']['b']
...
```

In a loop, (if you gave unique letters to to each check box) it might go a bit like this:

```
foreach($_POST['day'] as $key=>$val){
    echo "<p>$key = $val</p>";
}
```

output:

```
a = 50 kg flour-50ksh
b = 50 kg milk-150ksh
c = 50 kg maize-50ksh
d = 50 kg oil-50ksh
e = 50 kg rice-50ksh
f = 50 kg soap-50ksh
g = 50 kg juice-50ksh
```

Comment: @J.Kaita is this what you mean?

Comment: @ mickmackusa  sth else came up... what if i wanted to get the values placed in the checkbox form from a database(ie both price and quantity)I have a simple database...Name:deliveries  Table:fastfood  Columns;  id,good,price  eg  {1 .50 kg juice. 50}

Comment: This feels like a completely separate question.  If my answer to this question is what you wanted, please award it the green tick.  If you would like someone to fix an existing database query that you have written, please ask a new question -- this is how SO is meant to work.  We, volunteers, are not meant to write code for free; we are meant to correct codes that do not work.